# iOS: how do I dynamically change a uiscrollview's minZoom every time its bounds are changed?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview

I suppose I could subclass it and override minZoom's getter method but is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view controller override this -

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
```

When a view’s bounds change, the view adjusts the position of its subviews. Your view controller can override this method to make changes before the view lays out its subviews.

if this is too soon theres a viewDidLayoutSubviews

Change your scrolllviews zoom there.